# How to get this effect in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

Often in games, if the characters pics up a coin or some special thing, that item is enlarged to fill the whole screen, and then shrink. It's enlarged "from" where it was picked up or clicked, and shrinks again back to that point.

I can probably get this right using the slow approach of:

1. creating a div with the image to be enlarged
2. use settimeout to gradually change the size of the image

But I was hoping there is a better way that will make it more slick?

Comment: Is there an example you can point us to by any chance?

Comment: See [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)